# Python distutils exclude setup.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, rpm, distutils

My `setup.py` script is simple:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='my-awesome-app', 
    version='1.0', 
    scripts=['my-awesome-app.py'],
    )
```

And the file structure is:

```
my-awesome-app/
    my-awesome-app.py
    setup.py
```

In theory I am only including `my-awesome-app.py` in the distribution. In practice `setup.py` ends up in the RPM too.
I don't see a point of including `setup.py` there, is there a way to force distutils to leave this file out?
I am using python 2.7, I build my RPM by running `python setup.py bdist_rpm`.
Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setup.py` is required because when the package is installed in your environment, the following command is run:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

Running `python setup.py bdist_rpm` only creates a *distribution* package that you can give to others. `setup.py` is still required to do the installation.

Comment: I gave up on this tool anyway, seems like it acts completely differently on my Mac, on my VM and on my CI server. On some of them it doesn't copy some files and fails, on other it precompiles my python scripts and later fails. With unpredictable behaviour like that I don't think it's the right tool to use in production...

Answer (score 0):

You can always create the spec file manually and leave out the setup.py.
For example and more details see:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Python#Example_common_spec_file